# How we swipe more than 2 images in iOS horizontally?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

i write the below code to swipe 2 images. it works fine
but now my task is to swipe more than 2 images horizontally.
and also at the last image if we swipe to the left the first image should appear

how can i achieve this?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad    
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // instantiate gesture recognizer

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

//setup images
image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
imageView.image = image1;

}

-(void)didSwipe : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
 {
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = sender.direction;
switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        imageView.image = image2;
        break;

    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft :
        imageView.image = image1;
        break;


    default:
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Use scrollview with paging property.

Comment: You can do it with images count. If you have image array then check it if swipe image is last image then start it with array Object at index 0

Comment: this third party control might be what u are looking for http://code4app.net/ios/loop-ScrollView/4fdaa4676803faab3d000000

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and you will get desired output.
In the following code you app will use album photos and automatically sets size of the scrolling as per the number of images in album.

```
-(void)getAllPictures
{


    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != nil) {
            if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
                [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

                NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]; 

                [library assetForURL:url
                         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                             [mutableArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];

                             if ([mutableArray count]==count)
                             {
                                 imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray];
                                 [self allPhotosCollected:imageArray];
                             }
                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!"); } ]; 

            } 
        }
    };

    NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            [assetGroups addObject:group];
            count=[group numberOfAssets];
        }
    };

    assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"There is an error");}];
}



-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray
{


    CGSize imageSize;

    imageSize.width= imageView.bounds.size.width;
    imageSize.height = imageView.bounds.size.height;
    self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    self.scrollView.frame = imageView.frame;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * imgArray.count, imageSize.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.bounces=YES;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [self.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    CGFloat xPos = 0.0;

    for (UIImage *image in imgArray) {
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);


         [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        xPos += imageSize.width;
        // assuming ARC, otherwise release imageView

    }



}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20,320 , 420)];
    [self getAllPictures];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your multiple images in NSArray.

Now check condition for swipe right if yes than display image from that array.

and if swipe left than display previous image from that array..

Easy to use for loop and increment operator.

I hope you will get idea.